# Rendered image over background image looks over-exposed

Tags: rendering, node-editor, light, lighting, hdri

I want to render a 3D model on a background image and I also use shadow catcher on a ground plane. It all looks perfect when I do a simple render in the viewport (Shift + Z), but when I do a real render with the node setup as in the image below, the background image seems to be over exposed with to much light!

Is it the light from HDRI-image that affect the background? If so, is there a way to prevent the light from affecting the background image? Or are there other better options to handle this?

[image]

Comment: Please use the [edit] link at the bottom of your question (https://i.stack.imgur.com/lXFuK.png) and add more information: what settings are you using for color management? Add also an image of the result you are gettng.

Comment: Your image node is cannot be affected by what you put in place in your scene, unless you adjust it yourself by setting up brightness node